# Storing and retrieving user data in android apps?

Tags: java, android, networking, google-play-services, android-studio-2.1

I'm very new to development and would like to create an app for an android TBS game that I would also like to build on later by developing a desktop application. I'd like to know how to go about storing user data in a secure way that would allow the user to be able to sign in on a possible future desktop application. From what I've read on data storage, I think what I need is to store a sheet containing fields for the user's email, password, username, and a class containing player specific stats on a web based service. How can I also take advantage of google play services to help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a read at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by looking into Firebase, a platform that was acquired by Google and has seen some great overhauls lately. It gives you free storage and database space (up to a certain level of usage of course) and works cross-platform for Web, Android and iOS.

Check out https://firebase.google.com/ for the docs and some quick-start guides as well as presentations from the latest Google IO: https://www.youtube.com/user/Firebase/videos

Answer (score 0):

Android Game Services allows you to Store user data, to set achievements, to share informations with social medias, to make a leaderboard and to make a multiplayer game.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/

You should use them for cross platform purpose.

Comment: I don't see anything there showing how I can create and store the fields I mentioned, and Play Games Service looks like something meant for mini games. I want to store variable and classes online as part of the player's stats. Maybe there's a specific page/guide to using it I haven't seen?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Android Doc in storage options:
[Data-Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

If you want share in future the data with desktop, you will need the data in some online storage. Check Firebase, from Google, or Parse.

- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
- [Parse](https://parse.com/docs)